# Updating Biztalk Application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a biztalk application ( with one orchestration ) which I send a select through WCF and it returns the data from one view in the SQL server.

My Question:
I'm going to have more views on the server, what is the proper way to update the application?

What i've been thinking so far:
I don't think it makes sense to have multiple applications, and multiple wcf services. So the steps I think are needed:

1. Generate the new schema;
2. Create the new orchestrations;
3. Deploy the application;
4. Republish the WCF Service;
5. Configure the new orchestration in the biztalk.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Are you just using `BizTalk` to publish read-only WCF data services from your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, yes, those are the steps.

Since you refer to applications, a few points just to make sure.
1. You would add the new WCF SQL Schemas, Maps and Orchestrations to the same Visual Stuido Solution, perhaps even the same Project.
2. That solution is your Deployment unit and the output of all the Projects go into the same Application in BizTalk Administrator.
3. Once Deployed, yes, configure (bind) new Orchestrations and andy new servcies.

In short, you'd have only one Visual Studio Solution and one Application in BizTalk Administrator.

Comment: Thanks. I think I just didn't explain myself properly in a bit of the question. I have a console application( C# ) that sends the selects, in which I created the service and generated the WCF access.

So if i'm understanding correctly after I change the biztalk app, I can just use the wcf publishing wizard again to overwrite the older service?

Comment: From a client perspective, yes.  For new/modified services, you'd have to update.  On the BizTalk side, also yes, you'd run the Wizard for any new/modified Orchestrations published as services.